# Does jQuery have any function to determine the tag type of the DOM element(s) referenced by jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, dom

Does jQuery have any function to determine the tag type of the DOM element(s) referenced by  jQuery object? I am writing a jQuery plugin and...

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin() {
    return this.each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       // <---------------------------------------HERE!
    });
}
```

I would like to know if `this` is an `<input>` element or a `<div>` element, without directly using the DOM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
this.nodeName;
```

...or to be safe, convert it to a specific case:

```
this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
```

The `nodeName` property is a property that is [widely supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t20) and will give you the tag name in the case of an element node (as in your case).

Comment: Great link for why `nodeName` is better than `tagName`.

Comment: @Box9: I was going to paste that note from quirksmode about `tagName` in the answer, but thought I'd just let it be instead. But yeah, nodeName is the way to go. :o)

Answer (score 3):

Why not directly use the DOM? Since you have a DOM object already handy in `this` I'd say just use it. If you *only* had the jQuery object you could do:

```
$this.attr("tagName") == "DIV"
```

or

```
$this.is("div")
```

But there's no need for that.

Comment: I would say being able to access the `tagName` through `attr` is a side-effect of jQuery removing the distinction between properties and attributes, and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tagName`:

```
this.tagName; //notice this is the DOM element not the jQuery object.
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName

Answer (score 0):

apply the method `prop("tagName")` for getting the tagname of the html element for example:

```
$this.prop("tagName");
```