# jQuery: Get selected element tag name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, htmlelements

Is there an easy way to get a tag name?

For example, if I am given `$('a')` into a function, I want to get `'a'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does jQuery have any function to determine the tag type of the DOM element(s) referenced by jQuery object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113386/does-jquery-have-any-function-to-determine-the-tag-type-of-the-dom-elements-ref)

Answer (score 1139, accepted):

You can call `.prop("tagName")`. Examples:

```
jQuery("<a>").prop("tagName"); //==> "A"
jQuery("<h1>").prop("tagName"); //==> "H1"
jQuery("<coolTagName999>").prop("tagName"); //==> "COOLTAGNAME999"
```

If writing out `.prop("tagName")` is tedious, you can create a custom function like so:

```
jQuery.fn.tagName = function() {
  return this.prop("tagName");
};
```

Examples:

```
jQuery("<a>").tagName(); //==> "A"
jQuery("<h1>").tagName(); //==> "H1"
jQuery("<coolTagName999>").tagName(); //==> "COOLTAGNAME999"
```

Note that tag names are, by convention, returned **CAPITALIZED**. If you want the returned tag name to be all lowercase, you can edit the custom function like so:

```
jQuery.fn.tagNameLowerCase = function() {
  return this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
};
```

Examples:

```
jQuery("<a>").tagNameLowerCase(); //==> "a"
jQuery("<h1>").tagNameLowerCase(); //==> "h1"
jQuery("<coolTagName999>").tagNameLowerCase(); //==> "cooltagname999"
```

Comment: AS of jQuery 1.6, this should be `.prop`.

Comment: Is the capitalisation convention followed by all browsers? If not, does jQuery normalise this?

Comment: tagName is part of the DOM spec and is always capitalized.

Comment: Note that the string that's returned is in CAPITAL LETTERS. This'll be a gotcha if you're trying to compare it to "div" or "a" for example.

Comment: using `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` may be helpful when comparing `prop('tagName')` result to a tag name.

`if($("my_selector").prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'div')` or `if($("my_selector").prop("tagName").toUpperCase() == 'DIV')`

Comment: In reply to @tilleryj's reply, capitalized should be camelCase'd. In any case, to sum up:

- DOM spec props are always camelCase
- The return is in uppercase; use .toLowerCase() to compare to e.g. 'div' or 'select'
- Best practice is using .prop('tagName') as jQuery prevents JS errors

Comment: @tilleryj
"Note that tag names are, by convention, returned CAPITALIZED" - no, they are returned in **all capitals**. Capitalisation implies only the first letter to be capital, while other letters in lower case.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to get the tag name from the "<div class="login-header">" type. actually I am looping through all th content inside body tag and I need all the tag names inside it and there ids and classes.

Comment: I downvoted instead of upvoted by mistake and now I can't change it — sorry @tilleryj!

Comment: Working Fine :)

Answer (score 104):

You can use the DOM's [`nodeName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeName):

```
$(...)[0].nodeName
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great - although I'll use the more jQueryish version because I'm in a jQuery world at the moment.

Comment: pure JS solutions (like this one) are generally superior to jQuery ones especially if they do not suffer from browser compatibility problems or are much more verbose.

Comment: ... and specifically because of those browser incompatibility issues, the jQuery ones are often superior if someone is picking a solution and isn't well-versed in what browser-incompatibilities to watch out for. ;)

Comment: I consider this superior because it doesn't matter what the jQuery version is, this solution works on all versions. +1

Comment: particularly if you are in a each()-like situation, where you have to cast the element back to a jquery object to get a property that was already there, like `$(this).prop('tagname')`. this.nodeName is often more efficient. +1

Comment: I think this should of been the accepted answer. There arent any browser compatibility issues, its faster and simpler.

Answer (score 62):

As of jQuery 1.6 you should now call prop:

```
$target.prop("tagName")
```

See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 53):

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
jQuery('selector').prop("tagName").toLowerCase()
```

**Older versions**

```
jQuery('selector').attr("tagName").toLowerCase()
```

`toLowerCase()` is not mandatory.

Comment: Why are you doing `new String`?

Comment: Because toLowerCase() is a method of String

Answer (score 26):

This is yet another way:

```
$('selector')[0].tagName
```

Comment: Nice one! Clearer than nodeName and even shorter. :P

Answer (score 12):

You should **NOT** use `jQuery('selector').attr("tagName").toLowerCase()`, because it only works in older versions of Jquery.

You **could** use `$('selector').prop("tagName").toLowerCase()` if you're certain that you're using a version of jQuery thats >= version 1.6.

---

#### Note :

You may think that EVERYONE is using jQuery 1.10+ or something by now (January 2016), but unfortunately that isn't really the case. For example, many people today are still using Drupal 7, and every official release of Drupal 7 to this day includes jQuery 1.4.4 by default.

So if do not know for certain if your project will be using jQuery 1.6+, consider using one of the options that work for ALL versions of jQuery :

**Option 1 :**

```
jQuery('selector')[0].tagName.toLowerCase()
```

**Option 2**

```
jQuery('selector')[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 2):

nodeName will give you the tag name in uppercase, while localName will give you the lower case.

```
$("yourelement")[0].localName
```

will give you : yourelement instead of YOURELEMENT