# How to get the name of the current selected HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagname

I have selected some tag with jQuery:

```
$('select, :checkbox, :radio').each(function(){
   // ...
});
```

Now, I need to get the name of the current tag:

```
$('select, :checkbox, :radio').each(function(){
   var tag_name = $(this). ???
   alert(tag_name);
});
```

Expected result: "select", "input" and so on.

So, I need to know, how to get the tag name of element. Maybe without jQuery, with native javascript functions - no matter how.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all! There a lot of very usefull information in all your answers.

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name/9538913#9538913

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the HTML DOM native [tagName](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName) property.
Try this:

```
var tag_name = this.tagName;
```

Comment: see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name

Answer (score 4):

```
$('select, :checkbox, :radio').each(function(){
   var tag_name = this.tagName;
   alert(tag_name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `this.tagName` will give you the node name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select, :checkbox, :radio').each(function(){
   alert($(this).get(0).nodeName);
});
```

Comment: this.tagName might be better actually... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/different-between-tagname-and-nodename-jquery

Answer (score 1):

sure... very simple

**Here is a working example**

http://jsfiddle.net/L96KG/

here is the reference source

[Can jQuery provide the tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
$('select, :checkbox, :radio').each(function(el){
    alert(el.tagName);
});
```