# jQuery tag name of element

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I'm try to get an elements tag name in jQuery.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="section" id="New_Revision">

    <h1>New Revision&nbsp<img alt="Lock_closed" class="edit" data-id="1" src="/assets/lock_closed.svg" /></h1>

    <p>This is a test paragraph.</p>

    <ol class="references">
      <li>test</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.section").children().each(function(){
        alert($(this).tagName + " - " + $(this).html());
    });     
})
```

I've tried `$(this).tagName`, `$(this).nodeName` and `$(this).attr("tag")` as noted in this question: [Can jQuery provide the tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name)

But I'm always getting `undefined` in return. The `html()` outputs correctly. Why can't I get the tag name of each element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get selected element tag name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try

`this.nodeName` instead of `$(this).nodeName`

`this` refers to the DOM element itself and `$(this)` wraps the element up in a jQuery object.

**EDIT**

If you require Jquery approach you can use

```
$(this).prop("tagName")
```

Comment: this is using javascript not Jquery as stated in the question.

Comment: @Floradu That is what I also stated here.DOM means document object model.Why downvote?

Comment: as I stated before, he wanted a Jquery approach, not an Js approach, I removed the downvote

Comment: Thanks, this is simplest solution.

Comment: Well, if you really had wanted to use a jQuery function for some reason, you could have used $(this).prop('tagName') - but it's easier to just use this.tagName as ssilas777 said.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

```
$(this).attr("id", "rnd" + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + "_" + i.toString());
```

As stated in the linked question. Also there is a big difference between *$(this)* and *this*

Tried this in the browser console and it works:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].tagName // this uses javascript
```

this uses jquery:

```
$('a').get(0).nodeName; // this works for jquery
```

try this:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.section").children().each(function(){
        alert(this.tagName + " - " + $(this).html());
    });     
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I having trouble seeing how to adapt this to the `$(this).tagName` code above.