# Get elements 'tag name' by searching Class name

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to get element tag name which is associated with the element with a certain class name.

I know I can do these two lines of code to get the class name and the tag name.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("regeneratePostnatal");
document.getElementsByClassName(returnedPatientID);
```

I'm just asking if there is a way of doing something like below to get the tag name which belongs to the element with the class name?

```
document.getElementsByClassName(returnedPatientID).tagName
```

**Example**

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("oneID")[0].tagName;
document.getElementById("returnedValue").innerHTML = element;

var element2 = document.getElementsByClassName("oneID")[0].nodeName;
document.getElementById("returned2Value").innerHTML = element2;
```

```html
<a class="oneID" name='regeneratePostnatal'>Click</a>
<div id="returnedValue"></div>
<div id="returned2Value"></div>
```

**I'm trying to get the name attribute value so that it'll show "regeneratePostnatal"**

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Which tagName are you looking for? First, last, all?

Comment: You can use `tagName` or `nodeName` for that. Make sure `returnedPatientID` is a class, because it implies an Id :)

Comment: It is `tagName`, with a capital 'N'

Comment: You can find the answer to your question in below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get the attribute *name* value?

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("oneID")[0].getAttribute('name');
document.getElementById("returnedValue").innerHTML = element;
```

```html
<a class="oneID" name='regeneratePostnatal'>Click</a>
<div id="returnedValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is `nodeName`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(returnedPatientID)[0].nodeName
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodename.asp)

Comment: `tagName` is the same as `nodeName`. The problem is `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple results

Comment: Right, almost the same, you are right, but is `tagName`, not `tagname` as he wrote it.

Comment: I'm currently only getting a value back of "A". I've updated my question to show you the example

Comment: Well `'A'` is definitely the tag name of the tag which has '`oneID`' in its `classList`...

Comment: @laruiss How would I go about getting the attribute value of name = "regeneratePostnatal" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the `tagName` but you need to use `index` as `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of array. So to get the tagName:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('YourClass')[0].tagName);

//Or in a loop
var len = document.getElementsByClassName('YourClass').length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('YourClass')[i].tagName);
}
```