# How to extract value from table with mixture of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which contains a combination of plain text, input textboxes, selects, and spans. I need to iterate through the table row by row and pull out the value in each cell. Within my table all `<tr>` have a particular css class.

```
  $(".gridBody").each(function(rowindex){
                $(this).find("td").each(function(cellIndex){
                   var cell = $(this).first()
   })
```

In my debugger I can see what kind of object is being returned by $(this).first() but I can't find out how to get into its attributes. I have tried using jqueries html parser to turn it back into a dom element, but instead of getting, for example, a textbox, I get something like [[html inputtextbox]]. Most of the methods that work on regular dom elements are not working for me.

If I use $(this)[0].innerText it returns the correct value when the contents of the cell are plain text, but not when they are a form of input or nested in a span element. What I would really like to be able to do is get a regular html dom element back that I can then check the type of with $.is() and then vary much logic from there.

How do I get the first child element in a table cell as an html dom element that I can manipulate with jquery like any other dom element?

Comment: Maybe a jsFiddle with your table data in it?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name if you want to identify the type of tag you are handling.  Do you always know that the object you want the value of is the first thing inline?

Comment: on a side-note, when iterating a jquery collection with `.each` then in that context `$(this) === $(this).first()` since `this` corresponds to a single element in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
var collected = $("#myTable td").find("input, textarea, span").map(function(){
  return this.value || this.textContent;
}).get();

console.log( collected ); // an array holding values or text
```

http://jsbin.com/zewixe/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

If you want only the immediate children than use the right `>` selector

```
(">input, >textarea, >span")
```

Comment: This works great for input boxes and spans, but it misses the plan text. Something like <tr class="gridBody"><td>plain text</td></tr>. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I would do it:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <h1>Some stuff.</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <input type="text" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input type="text" value="2"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <input type="text" value="3"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <input type="text" value="4"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

$(function() {

```
function getFormData(selector){
    'use strict';

    var formTypes = {
        text: 'text',
        radio: 'radio',
        select: 'select'
    },
    values = [];

    $(selector).children().each(function(idx, childNode) {
        if (childNode.getAttribute('type') && formTypes[childNode.getAttribute('type')]) values.push(childNode.value);
    }); 

    return values;
}

alert(
    getFormData('table tr td.someClass')
    );
```

})();

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/RaKGjZ