# How to fetch name from select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a number of select tags. Every tag is differed by their name.
So when I do submit the form, I need to get the name of the select tag using jquery.

```
<select class="myclass" id="" name="AP">
<option value="">Select Val</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="60">60</option>
</select>

var getSelect = $('.compressor option:selected');
console.log(getSelect.name);
```

I didn't the same for the input field it is working. When I kept my name in options it is working fine. But I don't want to keep my name attr in options.

Comment: You are not selecting the `select` element, but the `option` element. If you select the `select` element, it works like for an `input` element.

Comment: is it possible to find whether it is dropdown or input using element class?

Comment: If you have a jQuery reference to an element, you can know what it is with `.prop("tagName")`. That will return `OPTION`, `SELECT`, or `INPUT`, ... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the attribute *name* of the *select* element, remove `option:selected` from the selector. You can use `attr()` to get specific attribute:

```js
var getSelect = $('.myclass');
console.log(getSelect.attr('name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myclass" id="" name="AP">
<option value="">Select Val</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="60">60</option>
</select>
```

If you want `option:selected` as part of the selector then you have to target the `parent()` element:

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var getSelect = $('.myclass option:selected').parent();
  console.log(getSelect.attr('name'));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myclass" id="" name="AP">
<option value="">Select Val</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="60">60</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

***Update:*** To get the element's name you can use the property *tagName*

```
//using index
console.log(getSelect[0].tagName);
//or: using prop()
console.log(getSelect.prop('tagName'));
```

```js
var getSelect = $('.myclass');
getSelect.each(function(){
  console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myclass" id="" name="AP">
<option value="">Select Val</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="60">60</option>
</select>
<input class="myclass"/>
```

Comment: is it possible to find whether it is dropdown or input using element class?

Comment: @SethuKarthik, yes it is possible, to get the element tag name you can use *tagName* ...Please see the updated answer.....thanks