# How to read selected row(tr) column(td) data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

In my MVC project, Need to find selected row(tr), first child(td) data-attribute and control tagName also need to set the attribute attr('checked', 'checked');

HTML

```
<table class="availableProduct">
    <tr>
        <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="product-group" data-productid="SAP003" 
                data-id="Annual-46-4" data-optionid="46">
        </td>
        <!-- FIND THIS -->
        <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="product-group" data-productid="SAP0031" 
            data-id="Annual-46-14" data-optionid="461">
        </td>
        <!-- FIND THIS -->
        <td>foobar2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="product-group" data-productid="SAP0032" 
            data-id="Annual-46-42" data-optionid="462">
        </td>
        <!-- FIND THIS -->
        <td>foobar2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
    $('table.availableProduct tr').click(function (e) {
       var temp=$(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
    });
```

jQuery temp variable value is following

```
<input type="checkbox" class="product-group" 
data-productid="SAP003" data-id="Annual-46-4" data-optionid="46">
```

On this selection want to do the following

- read all data-attribute values
- set attr('checked', 'checked');
- Need to read the tagName

Comment: Get all attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery
set checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Get tagname https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name

Comment: All easily findable if you actually bothered to do a bit of searching / researching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the current element clicked

`$(this).find('td .product-group');`  find the element with class `product-group`.

Use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get all the data attributes on the element.

Set checked using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
$('table.availableProduct tr').click(function(e) {
  var inp = $(this).find('td .product-group');
  inp.prop('checked', !inp.prop('checked')); // toggle check and uncheck
  var dataAttributes = inp.data();
  console.log(dataAttributes);
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vf6e0pt7/)</kbd>