# how can i use JQuery with getElementsById?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

i have this variable

```
formEditable = document.getElementById("formid").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

i want it like that

```
formEditable = $("#formid").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Get selected element tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347357/jquery-get-selected-element-tag-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single selector string instead:

```
const inputsInsideForm = $('#formid input');
```

This will give you a jQuery collection of all `input` elements which are descendants of the `#formid` element.

If you *had* to use `getElementsByTagName` instead, extract the element from the `$("#formid")` collection first:

```
$("#formid")[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

This will give you a live HTMLCollection of those inputs.

Comment: But **ID** is unique and `$("#formid")[0]` does what? Takes first ID from one ID? If `getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` - yes, it's Ok, cause it returns an array.

Comment: Yes, IDs are (or should be) unique, but `$(selector)` will *always* return a jQuery collection, not the underlying element. In this case, the jQuery collection will contain a single value (but, in general, jQuery collections can contain more, or zero, values). Regardless of the number of elements in the collection, `[0]`, `[1]`, etc is one of the ways to extract an underlying element from the collection - just like `querySelectorAll`

Comment: I wanna say `$("#formid")[0]` useless move. `$("#formid")` always returns the first one ID. BTW [it raises an error](https://jsfiddle.net/ba3fw0Lh/).

Comment: Yeah, I think it's pretty silly too - I'd always prefer `$('#formid input');` by far. Problem is that you can't use `getElementsByTagName` on a jQuery collection, and OP was trying to use `getElementsByTagName` (maybe part of a homework requirement?) so I included that to show how it could be used in combination with the jQuery method of selecting elements, even though it seems pretty silly

Comment: Yes, using a jQuery method on something which is not a jQuery collection will indeed throw an error. (`$("#s")[0]` is, of course, not a jQuery collection, it's a single element. not sure what you were expecting there. * extract the element from the $("#formid") collection first:* in the answer meant that one will have the *element*, not a jQuery collection)

Answer (score 2):

In case you have many `<input>`s in the page, you should use

```js
// Locate the first element with ID `formid`,
// then query its descendants for `<input>` elements.
formEditable = $("#formid").find("input");
```

for performance reasons since selectors are evaluated right-to-left.

When using the query `$("#formid input")`, first all `<input>`s are located, then they are filtered based on their ancestor elements, looking for an ancestor with ID `formid`.

This is nothing unique to jQuery, but your original solution actually takes this into account:

```js
formEditable = document.getElementById("formid").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Note that jQuery queries return a jQuery Object, not a `DOMNodeList` of elements. So the variable `formEditable` will be a jQuery Object. To convert a jQuery Object to an array, use the `toArray` method.

Answer (score -2):

You Can simply use below code :

```
$("#formid").getElementsByTagName("input");
```